# redux-form(v6)をtypescriptで使いたい

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

redux-formをtypescriptで利用しているかに質問です。
やりたいことは「redux-form(v6)をtypescriptで使いたい」です。

typescriptはv2を利用。
redux-formの型定義を@typesで取得するとv4のものが取得されます。
https://gist.github.com/rluiten/a41fb5845fae11a5484bad954d97b3a8
のv6の.d.tsをコピーすることで動くには動くのですが.d.tsをアップデートすると上書きされてしまいます。
その為、現在はcomponentのみjsxで実装しtypescriptを使用しない方向で検討中です。

とりうる選択肢として下記が思いつきました。
・redux-form(v6)+.d.td自作
・redux-form(v6)+jsxを使う
・redux-form(v5以下)+typescriptを使う

可能な限りtypescriptを使いたいのですが、他にも.d.tsが無い or バージョンの低いライブラリが
いくつもあり、react+typescriptは時期尚早なのかと思ってきています。

似たような状態で、有効な策をお持ちの方がおりましたら助けてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

任意の型定義ファイルを使いたいのであれば、
そのファイルをソースディレクトリ内に入れてしまって
`@types/redux-form` を npmのdependenciesから削除してしまえばよいです。